# Media Query and Linear-Gradient is not being detected by IE

Tags: css, media-queries

I have the following media queries that are specific for all IE's. When I go to IE11 or older, the browser does not that detect my media queries.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
   @media screen (min-width:1281px){
    .topleft {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        left: -16% !important;
    }

    .bgimg {
        width: 69%;
        left: 15%;
    }
}

@media screen (max-width: 1280px){
    .middle1 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 44% !important;
        left: 33% !important;
        width: 38% !important;
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        text-align: center;
    }
}
</style><![endif]-->
```

My second question I have is I am unable to do a linear-gradient correctly in IE.

I was able to find reference on here on how to accomplish it. However, when I do `-ms-linear-gradient(...)`, it does create the gradient but it covers the background image that I have. How can I achieve it without the background image being blacked out?

```
background-image: url('http://oc2-reatest/OCUpgrade52/images/Stethoscope_ver2.jpg');/*, -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0 0%, #f0f0f0 10%);

/*filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#f0f0f0', endColorstr='#f0f0f0');/*For IE7-8-9*/ */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that in your stylesheet (i.e. separate css file)? (conditional comments only work in HTML files)

If not (i.e. if it is in the HTML file), it's important that it follows *after*  including your general stylesheet, since otherwise it would be overwritten by the general styles.

And a third possible cause: There might be rules with a higher specifity in the general styles which overrule those in your IE media queries. For example, if there is a rule like `.container_all .topleft`, it will have a higher specifity than your `.topleft` rule and overrule it. To avoid that, search for the selectors in the general stylesheets and use the same ones in your media queries.

Comment: @ Johannes: Yes, it is after the general stylesheet and you are correct, it is in the HTML File where I am doing the styling right now. and for your response, I did you the same selectors from the general stylesheets. However, it still did not override those changes with the changes I am trying to do

Comment: I found this answer concerning IE9 - maybe that helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15442638/5641669, and this concerning IE10: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20114855/5641669

Comment: Johannes: Thank you so much . That is actually helped a lot.